# I am trying to move a file from sdcard to another device folder and it fails with error that file is not there, but it is!

Tags: file-system

I am trying to move a file from `/sdcard` to another device file and I am getting the following:

`mv: bad 'xxxxxxxx.0': No such file or directory`

while `ls -l` shows the file in directory.

The device is physical one, not an emulator and it is rooted.
Why is this happening? 
`file <file>` confirms this is an ASCII file. I know cases that this was happening when someone was trying to move 32bit binary to 64bit device, but this is just an ASCII text file.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own question, the reason for that error is that I tried to move the file from an absolute path instead of a relative one, /sdcard instead of sdcard.

Using relative path worked.